# Python argparser option to call a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, argparse

I am wondering if it is possible to use argparser to easily determine which function should be called.

At the moment I take in a single parameter for a parameter file name, so it is called like:

```
python file_name.py -p parameter_file_name
```

What I would like to do is pass an argument before the parameter that dictates which function to call, like so:

```
python file_name.py functionA -p parameter_file_name
```

At the moment this is what I have for the single parameter:

```
# Define a parser to process the parameter file.
parser = ap.ArgumentParser(
    description='Test parser.')

parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='--parameter-file', type=ap.FileType('r'), action='store',
                    dest='parameters', required=True,
                    help='Path to json file containing parameters.')
```

Comment: did you try `sys.argv` in your script?, Argparse supports multiple args anyway

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) provides an example of how to do this.

Comment: If subcommands aren't what you're looking for, just make the command line argument a required one, not an optional one. Then, use a dict that matches the string with the relevant function (or use `getattr` to obtain the function directly from your module; less clear i.m.o. though, and prone to exploits of your script).